# "ImportError: No module name polygon", There is no place to download the module polygon

Tags: python, polygon

I am trying to Run a program made in python and I get the error:

"ImportError: No module name polygon"

I am using ubuntu, python 2.7 and EPD 7.3-1.

How can I download the package and the C-extension of module Polygon for python?

I've tried with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-polygon
sudo apt-get install python-polygon2
```

And nothing happened.

I downloaded the zip file: "Polygon2-2.0.6.rar" from the autor's page. After that i extract Polygon2-2.0.6.rar onto Polygon2-2.0.6, then i go to that folder 
and run python setup.py install

wich give me:

```
jose@jose-Satellite-L845:~/Descargas/Polygon2-2.0.6$ python setup.py install

Using NumPy extension!
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'Polygon.cPolygon' extension

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DDEFAULT_STYLE=STYLE_LIST -DWITH_NUMPY=1 -Isrc -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/gpc.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/gpc.o

src/gpc.c: In function ‘gpc_read_polygon’:
src/gpc.c:1037:9: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

fscanf(fp, "%d", &(p->num_contours)); ^

src/gpc.c:1044:11: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

 fscanf(fp, "%d", &(p->contour[c].num_vertices));
       ^

src/gpc.c:1047:13: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

   fscanf(fp, "%d", &(p->hole[c]));
         ^
src/gpc.c:1054:13: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fscanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

   fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf", &(p->contour[c].vertex[v].x),
         ^

src/gpc.c: In function ‘gpc_polygon_clip’:

src/gpc.c:1471:31: warning: ‘dy’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

   build_intersection_table(&it, aet, dy);
                           ^

src/gpc.c:1460:12: warning: ‘yt’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

     if (edge->top.y == yt)
        ^

src/gpc.c:1328:20: warning: ‘tr’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

     vclass= tr + (tl << 1) + (br << 2) + (bl << 3);
                ^

src/gpc.c:1133:34: warning: ‘tl’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

int vclass, bl, br, tl, tr; ^

src/gpc.c:1133:30: warning: ‘br’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

int vclass, bl, br, tl, tr; ^

src/gpc.c:1133:26: warning: ‘bl’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

int vclass, bl, br, tl, tr; ^

src/gpc.c:1330:12: warning: ‘contributing’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

     if (contributing)
        ^

src/gpc.c: In function ‘gpc_tristrip_clip’:

src/gpc.c:2131:31: warning: ‘dy’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

   build_intersection_table(&it, aet, dy);
                           ^

src/gpc.c:2120:12: warning: ‘yt’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

     if (edge->top.y == yt)
        ^

src/gpc.c:1981:20: warning: ‘tr’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

     vclass= tr + (tl << 1) + (br << 2) + (bl << 3);
                ^

src/gpc.c:1794:34: warning: ‘tl’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

int vclass, bl, br, tl, tr; ^

src/gpc.c:1794:30: warning: ‘br’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

int vclass, bl, br, tl, tr; ^

src/gpc.c:1794:26: warning: ‘bl’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

int vclass, bl, br, tl, tr; ^

src/gpc.c:1983:12: warning: ‘contributing’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

     if (contributing)
        ^

src/gpc.c:2062:16: warning: ‘cft’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

         if (cft == LED)
            ^

src/gpc.c:2064:26: warning: ‘cf’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

           if (cf->bot.y == yb)
                      ^

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DDEFAULT_STYLE=STYLE_LIST -DWITH_NUMPY=1 -Isrc -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cPolygon.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/cPolygon.o

src/cPolygon.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio

    #include <Python.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `pip`? IE `pip install polygon` or something similar?

Comment: "…and he only have *.exe files". You overlooked the `.zip` files, which are source distributions you can install using Python.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE ANSWER. Yes i try to install that, but i failed.

Answer (score 1):

Download the zip file, unzip the file, cd into the folder, run `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`.

EDIT: Per your answer, you need to have python-dev installed .

Command is : `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: THANKS FOR THE ANSWER. Yes i try to install that, but i failed.

Comment: Thanks you very much for guide me, i installed python-dev, then i build and then install, almost done but at the end of install i get: error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Polygon': Permission denied

Comment: I answer to myself. What I had to do was install "python-dev". After that we run the "build" and then "install" (apparently the "build" was not necessary because the "install" does). Then, as the "install" throwing a permissions error, you have to gain administrator privileges: "sudo-su"
and then re-run the "install". Thank you very much to all for your responses. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next:

```
pip install Polygon3
```